# How to pass "form values" to thank you page 1st then to 3rd page "form."

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am trying to figure out how to pass "form values" from URL1 to a URL2 thank you page which has an "if" "else if" equation that decides based on a "yes" or "no" radio selection where to direct the user to the resulting URL3.

For example:  I need to pass the email value from this field on the URL1 form.

...through this URL2 "thankyou.php" page...

```
<?php

  //echo "<pre>"; print_r($_GET);

   if($_GET["inf_option_Areyouahomeowner"] == "226") {
       // I prefer to book a phone consultation.
       $url = "http://domain.ca/consult-request";
   } else {
       // Do not qualify.
       $url = "http://domain.ca/solar-options";
   }

   header("Location:".$url);

   ?>
```

...then the new form on the resulting page URL3 http://domain.ca/consult-request will have a hidden field containing the "email" field form the original form.

I've tried "as a non-php programmer to use session variables and php echo but no matter what I try the "email value" doesn't make it to URL3.

By the way, URL1 and URL3 are wordpress pages, so if I'm using Session variables I need to know where to put session start etc.

Answer (score 0):

There some very simple example for session:

1.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['value'] = 123;
echo '<a href="2.php">next</a>';
```

2.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo '<a href="3.php">next</a>';
```

3.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "value:".$_SESSION['value'];
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so based on the simple example that Philipp suggested and reading other posts, this is what I have so far....

1.php

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['inf_field_Email'] = $emailValue;

?>
```

form field:

```
<input type='text' class="inputForm" id="inf_field_Email"  ``name='inf_field_Email' size='60' placeholder="Enter Valid Email Here" />
```

2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['inf_field_Email']; 
?>
```

3.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['inf_field_Email']; 
 ?>
```

form field:

```
<input name="inf_field_Email" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['inf_field_Email']; ?>
```

However, the hidden field is still not being populated on 3.php.